# FindElement for an item in slide list while using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to find an Element while using webdriver but this item exists in a slide menu and I have to click next many times before seeing it and I am not sure also how to find it as by using firebug I can't get a unique id for this button or this item. Here is the example
go to this website
http://www.vodafone.de/privat/handys-tablets-tarife/smartphones-tarife.html

then you will find a slide list with phone devices. I want to slide till I find iPhone 6s and choose it.

[image]

I use findelement.by id always but this time I don't have any option for Id.

Comment: it will be helful if u can show us the image of the target area

Comment: just did it .. i want to click the back slide and then find iPhone 6s and click it. I am not sure how to identify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the Below code and see:

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.vodafone.de/privat/handys-tablets-tarife/smartphones-tarife.html");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='deviceSliderbuttonNext']/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000L);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='deviceSliderbuttonNext']/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000L);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='deviceSliderbuttonNext']/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000L);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='deviceSliderbuttonNext']/a")).click();
```

I ran this code and it is working fine.

Reply to me for further query and if you want to customize the code.
Happy Learning :-)

Comment: Perfect, the question is how did you find the id?

Comment: I'm not finding ID. I'm using xpath for the same. You can use any locator technique to find the element .
Refer this: It will help you : https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/selenium-locators


Happy Learning, :-)

You can use a plugin named firebug for mozilla firefox which gives you xpath or else you can create your own element locator either by Css or xpath.

Reply me for further query. :-)

Comment: hi can you please tell is this answer as per your question ?.you said in the last line "I want to slide till I find iPhone 6s and choose it." .where in the above code you select and stop.still if you are fine with answer then its ok

Comment: better to find it by id if you can! faster

Comment: @raj : I Just gave code where you can go till iphone 6s.

Comment: @Leon :In this case, The xpath is using ID only. So i guess it will be faster only. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: The script is not 100% ok but I customized it :) here is the right one WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     driver.get("http://www.vodafone.de/privat/handys-tablets-tarife/smartphones-tarife.html");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='deviceSliderbuttonPrev']/a")).click();

Comment: Yes . I just gave you initial thing. We can customize it for sure. I can create page object framework too. Where we can rehash the same thing again saving lots of line of code. That is why i mentioned in answer to that reply to me for customization. Hope I'm not wrong @Zomzomzom. :-)

Comment: @KishanPatel in this case yes but on future work you need to know that xpath is the last option to chose when you need to find element you can see more at : https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2015/06/29/are-xpath-locators-slower/

Comment: @Kishan it is perfect for my usage .. I got it now thank you

Comment: @Leon the problem is I can't find an id for this element .. could you do?

Comment: @Zomzomzom from browser right click on the element -> inspect

Comment: <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="buttonBig  cmConnectMoreButton" style="display: block;" onclick="s_objectID=&quot;javascript:%20void(0);_1&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true;">Weiter</a>
do you see and id here

Comment: The id is on the div the father of the a tag

Comment: in the xpath you can see that the first thing what we do is find the id and from it all the elements child that have tag name a.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("deviceSliderbuttonNext")).findElements(By.tagName("a"))[1].click();
```